# How can I make django write faster to database

Tags: django, postgresql, performance

I've a django project with postgresql backend.

An app is structured somewhat like

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    health_insurance_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    card_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=(
            ('Male', 'Male'),
            ('Female', 'Female'),
        ))
    dob = models.DateField()
    info = models.ForeignKey(SomeClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

At the end of every month, the client receives and updates the informatiton of it's patients.
New patient records uploaded monthly is as high as 400,000 records.

To track uploads, we do

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    enrolees = models.ManyToManyField(Enrolee)
```

and I'm using `WritableNestedSerializer` for Serializing both Upload and Patient. And I'm using a `ListCreateAPIView` from django-rest-framework to create Uploads.

Currently with postman, saving

- 1000 records takes ~6seconds
- 4000 records takes ~23seconds
- 1000 records on four different requuests (total 4000 records) take ~23seconds.

With this math, saving 400K records would take ~40 minuets. Is there a way to make this better?

Comment: Use `bulk_create`, `bulk_update`, etc. to update items in "bulk".

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using bulkcreate.

Comment: but do you send *multiple* records in the same API request?

Comment: I just added extra informattiton to clarrify.

Comment: I'm not explicitly using bulk_create, but WritableNestedSerializer should. I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing recommendations to use `bulk_create`, I dived into the hood to see what's going on with Django Rest Framework and it turned out It wasn't using `bulk_create`. It was simply iterating and creating one record at a time.

What I did, was implementt transaction on the `CreateAPIView` post method

```
class BatchCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BatchUploadSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic(savepoint=False):
            response =  super(BatchCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try using `bulk_create`**

`bulk_create` is a more efficient way to create simple objects in bulk. [Read more about it here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create). It speeds up things by preventing as many round trips to the database. The disadvantage is that things like `pre_save` and `post_save` will not be sent, so keep this in mind.

```
Entry.objects.bulk_create([
...     Entry(headline='This is a test'),
...     Entry(headline='This is only a test'),
... ])
```